# React native: error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'transformFile')

Tags: ios, react-native, npm

Can anyone guide me on following error,

```
at Bundler.transformFile (/Users/mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/Bundler.js:48:30)

at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async Object.transform (/Users/mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:101:12)
at async processModule (/Users/mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:137:18)
at async traverseDependenciesForSingleFile (/Users/mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:131:3)
at async Promise.all (index 0)

at async DeltaBundler.buildGraph (/Users/mobile-app/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler.js:50:5)

info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
OS: macOS 12.2.1
CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1038NG7 CPU @ 2.00GHz
Memory: 557.49 MB / 16.00 GB
Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 16.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/node
Yarn: Not Found
npm: 8.1.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.13.0/bin/npm
Watchman: 2022.02.21.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
Managers:
CocoaPods: 1.11.2 - /usr/local/bin/pod
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
  Platforms: DriverKit 21.2, iOS 15.2, macOS 12.1, tvOS 15.2, watchOS 8.3
Android SDK:
  API Levels: 23, 28, 29, 30, 32
  Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 32.0.0, 32.1.0
  System Images: android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-32 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64
  Android NDK: Not Found
IDEs:
Android Studio: 2021.1 AI-211.7628.21.2111.8139111
Xcode: 13.2.1/13C100 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
Languages:
Java: 11.0.8 - /usr/bin/javac
npmPackages:
@react-native-community/cli: Not Found
react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
react-native: 0.67.3 => 0.67.3
react-native-macos: Not Found
npmGlobalPackages:
*react-native*: Not Found
```

Comment: Did you try to delete and re-install node_modules?

Comment: Yes i tried all stuffs mentioned in StackOverflow, Finally adding @babel/preset-env worked.

Answer (score 2):

add openssl to nodeJs options as follow

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

if you are using terminal, you can write the above line before writing node command.
if you are using xcode to build, you can add to build options as in the below image

[image]

Comment: I get `node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS`

Comment: @marimaf try running  ```unset NODE_OPTIONS``` before the export command or change your node version using nvm ```nvm use v18```

Answer (score 0):

Adding @babel/preset-env to the package has finally fixed it. If deleting and re-installing node_modules didn't work, try this.

```
"devDependencies": {
  "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
  "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
  "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
  "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
  "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
  "eslint": "^6.8.0",
  "jest": "^25.1.0",
  "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.69.0",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked was to downgrade the node version from 20.3.1 to 16.0.0.

I found following article very useful if you want to switch between node versions for different projects.

Link: https://blog.logrocket.com/how-switch-node-js-versions-nvm/